# Make a layout with material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, material-ui, children

I don't know how to make a layout with a child page like this with material-ui. How do I build this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to setup angularjs, you also can setup material-ui.

1. Same angularjs. [ index file - setup data-ng-app="myapp" in html tag
2. for router use ui-router
3. setup app.js
4. use     
   for ui aesthetic

make individual view same all like angularjs

And whatever styling you want use material ui, as the document says.

Answer (score 0):

For styling you can use [material-ui grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/), then you can use React Router Link or something else and wrap the elements inside the Link (and set the Route in App.js if you use React Router). If you want your page as a child component, just import it as a component to the parent component and return it in the DOM.